# Как верно расставить знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

"Такое расстройство называют непереносимостью шума или боязнью шума в более тяжёлых случаях, к которым как раз относятся резкие раскаты грома."

Интуитивно я бы расставила так: "Такое расстройство называют непереносимостью шума, или боязнью шума - в более тяжёлых случаях, к которым как раз относятся резкие раскаты грома."

Answer (score 1):

*Такое расстройство называют **непереносимостью шума или боязнью шума в более тяжёлых случаях**, к которым как раз относятся резкие раскаты грома.*

Предложение оформлено верно,  дополнительные знаки препинания не нужны.

Пояснение

1. Союз ИЛИ здесь **одиночный разделительный**, а не пояснительный, поэтому запятая перед ним не ставится.

Сравним применение этих союзов на другом примере (из Розенталя):

Изменяемая часть слова называется **флексией или (называется) окончанием** (указаны два разных названия). **Флексия, или окончание**, имеется только у слов, относящихся к изменяемым частям речи (два разных названия используются в речи, причем пояснительный союз ИЛИ подчеркивает, что **оба названия относятся к одному предмету**).
https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

В нашем же случае расстройства **разные**, а пояснительный союз ИЛИ будет говорить, что они **одинаковые** (один и тот же предмет). Поэтому пояснительный союз ИЛИ сюда не подойдет.

2. Тире здесь не нужно, так как у нас  **единое сочетание**, которое произносится в одну фразу, без паузы. Смысл такой: непереносимость шума называют боязнью шума в более тяжёлых случаях (при более тяжелых расстройствах).

Здесь указаны два **разных** названия для  расстройства с **разной** степенью тяжести.  Если обособить тире весь пояснительный оборот, то его можно отнести ко всей конструкции, в то время как он поясняет **только второе название**.

3. Не стоит думать, что этой  информации  можно придать более ясную форму **в рамках одного предложения.** Если высказывание кажется недостаточно ясным, то текст следует **разделить на части.**

Answer (score 0):

> Интуитивно я бы расставила так: *"Такое расстройство называют
> непереносимостью шума, или боязнью шума — в более тяжёлых случаях, к
> которым как раз относятся резкие раскаты грома"*.

Если это расстройство *в более тяжёлых случаях* могут называть и "непереносимостью шума", и "боязнью шума",  то тире не нужно.

Если же *в более тяжёлых случаях* такое расстройство не называют "непереносимостью шума", то лучше это как-то пунктуационно обозначить.

Как вариант:

***Такое расстройство называют непереносимостью шума — или боязнью шума в более тяжёлых случаях, к которым как раз относятся резкие раскаты грома***.

Answer (score 0):

Я не медик, но мне кажется, что формулировки в предложении являются неверными.

[боязнь](http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Bojazn-2150.html)
**1.** (чего, перед кем-чем). Чувство опасения, страха. *Испытывать боязнь перед начальством. Боязнь высоты. Боязнь пространства* (болезненное состояние, при котором человек боится один переходить площадь, улицу и т. п.). *Ночь ненастная настала; На него боязнь напала* (Ершов).

[непереносимость](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Neperenosimost-15928.html)
**2.** *Мед.* Неспособность организма переносить что-либо. *Непереносимость боли. Непереносимость наркоза.*

Основываясь на определениях, я могу сделать предположение, что именно непереносимость — это самый тяжелый вид расстройства (иногда — даже смертельный).
У меня была собака, которая **боялась** грозы и фейерверков (просилась на руки или, наоборот, пыталась спрятаться). А вот соседская животинка страдала **непереносимостью** — ее тошнило и трясло, она гадила, выла и даже падала в обморок.

Я бы написала так:
Такое расстройство называют боязнью шума, а в более тяжёлых случаях, к которым как раз относятся резкие раскаты грома, — непереносимостью [шума].

[Акустикофобия, фонофобия, лигурофобия — страх громких звуков, шумов](https://psyhelp.am/ru/diseases/fhobias/other-isolated-phobias/ligyrophobia)